# What was probability like before Kolmogorov?

Tags: mathematics, probability

How was probability studied or understood before Kolmogorov axiomatized it?

I mean Bernoulli and Gauss had already started inventing and using distributions way before Kolmogorov came into the scene. There has also been measure theory in the making becoming the foundation of all probability theory.

Nowadays, in math pedagogy, we start with Kolmogorov's axioms and build our way to the normal distribution which is very ahistorical.

Comment: To answer this question, just look into any textbook which does not use measure theory. There are plenty of them, including those published long after Kolmogorov.